# How to use keys to influence movements on a window in python

Tags: python, tkinter, game-development, keystrokes

I am relatively new to programming and I've gotten into attempting to recreate classic arcade games to increase my knowledge of programming. Right now I'm trying to re-create Pong. I have created all the necessary animations for the game, but i have no idea how to assign key strokes. In the end I want to be able to press up and have my character and pong move up. How do I do this in Tkinter, or can I? if I can't do it in Tkinter what can I use to re-create this game?

Comment: Yes, Tkinter will work for this. It's called binding a function to a key press. Start here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm There's a lot of good examples out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to attach behavior to keys with with bindings. For example, assuming you have a canvas widget where you are doing your animations. If you want the up arrow key to call a function such as to change the direction of the paddle, you would create a binding like this:

```
def move_up(event):
    <put your "move up" code here>

the_canvas.bind("<Up>", move_up)
```

This will cause the `move_up` function to be called every time the user presses the "up" arrow key.

There are many places on the internet to learn about bindings. [Tkdocs.com](http://www.tkdocs.com/) is one such site. A tutorial on bindings can be found here: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/concepts.html#events